# Accessing and changing local variable inside while loop C#

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am currently trying to define two integer variables by user input. If the user inputs an integer which is not contained in the defined range, the user will be asked to input again, until the user inputs an accepted value.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a;
    int b;

    bool isAValid = false;
    bool isBValid = false;

    while (isAValid == false)
    {
        Console.Write("Input number from 2 to 20: ");
        isAValid = true;

        a = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

        if (a < 2 || a > 20)
        {
            isAValid = false;
        }
    }

    while (isBValid == false)
    {
        Console.Write("Input number from 2 to 20: ");
        isBValid = true;

        b = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

        if (b < 2 || b > 20)
        {
            isBValid = false;
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish, is saving the user input as **a** and **b** respectively, so the local variable value is defined as the user input value. However, when I try to access the local variable after the last while loop is broken, I get the "*Use of unassigned local variable **a** (or **b**)*".

Any ideas how I can define the variables, while still having the input prompt loop?

Comment: Please show the statement that the error refers to.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of posts on this site with the title "Use of unassigned local variable".  Read them and understand this error message.

Comment: @Eric Program flow afaics guarantees that they will have been assigned (unless an exception is thrown by the conversion); I suppose what puzzles the OP is that the compiler cannot see what we see: that the while loops are always entered, and hence the input and assignment always performed. I wonder if a (better suitable) do-while loop would help the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your error, declare this:

```
 int a = 0;
 int b = 0;
```

Instead of:

```
 int a;
 int b;
```

This will initialized your local variables and will fix your error message.

Comment: This is only a superficial fix: If indeed it is possible somehow to bypass assignment from input the default value will be indistinguishable from a possible input, and the error condition will go unnoticed. The program should ensure that either an assignment takes place or an error is handled. If it is indeed **im**possible to bypass input, the program should express that and not smooth it over with a redundant initialization.

Answer (score 1):

It's funny that the compiler cannot see that the `while` loops are always entered, and `a`  and `b`  are always initialized.

Update: Eric Lippert commented that for the purpose of flow control analysis *all expressions involving variables are considered possibly true or false;* even expressions like `x*0 == 0`.

*We* see that the `while` condition is always true, partly because we know this little logic pattern for input. We know what the loop is about. *The compiler* doesn't. <strike>It sees an arbitrary condition and can't be bothered to prove that it is always true.</strike> It simply considers all expressions with variables non-constant.

One way to fix this is to express the logic of the program better in the language. Such a pattern is not uncommon: "Repeat something until a condition is satisfied". In particular, *do it at least once in any case.* There is a language construct for that in all C family languages: The do/while loop. Rewriting the loop for `a` gives

```
do
{
    Console.Write("Input number from 2 to 20: ");
    isAValid = true;

    a = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

    if (a < 2 || a > 20)
    {
        isAValid = false;
    }
} while (isAValid == false);
```

Now I can access `a` after the loop; the compiler recognizes that the assignment will be guaranteed. The same should work for `b`.

This also enables us to write less cluttered code. The ancillary variable `isAValid` is needed only because of the "artificial" test when the while loop is first entered. The test is artificial because we do not have any input yet and hence cannot really test anything. If we indeed test only *after* the input, so that test data is available, we can put the test right into the condition. It boils down to

```
do
{
    Console.Write("Input number from 2 to 20: ");
    a = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

} while (a < 2 || a > 20);
```

Comment: It's not that the compiler team can't be bothered to do the work; rather, the language designers would rather have a clear, simple rule: all conditions that involve variables are considered to be possibly true or possibly false for purposes of analyzing control flow. Yes, this over-approximates reachability, but we *have* to over-approximate reachability if we want the compiler to terminate. The line has to be drawn *somewhere*, and the right decision is to pick a simple, clear, easy-to-explain position for that line.

Comment: @EricLippert Hey, I said "compiler", not "compiler *team*" ;-). It's just that we have become used to amazing compiler capabilities of inference which are sometimes not at all obvious to the casual observer (Linq). And then we have ` b=false; if(b)...`  and the compiler balks. Of course the line has to be somewhere. On the other hand I'd not be amazed if a compiler completely threw out a comparable `if` condition in an *optimizing pass* later on (after it has verified correctness). But then the user has indicated that waiting a little for an optimization is fine.

Comment: In fact I removed a bug in this area. In C# 2.0 the arithmetic optimizer ran before the definite assignment checker, which is wrong. `int x; int y = 1; if (y * 0 != 0) F(x);` was treated as `int x; int y = 1; if (false) F(x);` which is legal, but `y * 0  != 0` involves a variable, and by specification should be treated as possibly true. C# 3.0 does the arithmetic optimization after definite assignment checking.

Comment: @EricLippert As an aside: I am glad to have the opportunity to give my compliments to the past and present C# teams. The language is a joy to learn and use.

Comment: Thanks! It was a pleasure to work on it, and I enjoy keeping in touch with the team. They're awesome people.